# What is the most efficient way to compare an NSString in this way

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa-touch, parsing, comparison

I have an app (Cocoa Touch, Web Browser), however I need to be able to compare an NSString with thousands of other strings. Here's the deal.

When a WebView loads, I get the URL. I need to compare this URL with literally thousands of results (27,847). Each of those numbers represents a line of text in a plain text file.

I would like to know the best way to go about getting the data from the text file, and comparing it with the NSString. I need to know if the URL that the WebView is loading contains any of these strings.

The app needs to be very fast, so I can't just parse through every line in the text file, turn it into an array, and then compare each and every result.

Please share your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a magic way to compare them, you gotta compare them.

Comment: You probably want a hash table/map. NSDictionary can do this for you.

Comment: Well yeah. But what would be the fastest way to do that. Should I use NSDictionary, turn a bunch of them into NSStrings and keep them, another way?

Comment: @MikeWeller, Yes, I heard about that. Could you explain what a hash table/map is. I believe that is what somebody else mentioned I should try. I really don't know a lot about it though.

Comment: This somewhat depends on what you do next. If it's just 'yes or no' compare, you may be able to scan the file. If it's 'now tell on what line that occurred', it'll be different.

Comment: @estobbart, No, I just need a boolean compare. If it exists I should block.

Comment: How will you deal with URL variations? `http://server/foobar` `http://server/FOOBAR` (on an MS server) `http://server/foobar?123` `http://server/fooba%72` `http://server:80/foobar`etc? You can normalize, but it's a tough problem.

Comment: I'm not positive. The list does have a few variations, such as the ip address, but for what you mentioned I'm not sure.

Comment: The variations I listed are what the *user* could enter. They will all hit the same page. A simple string comparison will not match all of them.

Comment: Right. I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Don't forget to award an answer! It helps our reps :)

Comment: “I need to know if the URL that the WebView is loading contains any of these strings.” So you're not just testing equality, then? You're testing whether any of several thousand substrings is in the URL string?

Comment: Correct. Obviously, the URL would vary vastly. So I need to check to see if it contains a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution is to:

- Create a web service that can offload the work to a server and return a response. Since it sounds like you're building a web protection service, your database may grow to be quite substantial over time, and you can just scale your server up to increase its speed. Furthermore, you don't want to have to update your app every time the lookup data changes.

Other options are:

- Use a local SQLite database. SQL databases should perform lookups relatively fast.
- If you don't want to use any database, have you tried putting all the search strings into an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary object? This way, you would just check if the valueForKey: for the string you're searching for is nil.

Sample code for this:

```
NSDictionary *searchDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"google.com",
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"yahoo.com",
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"bing.com",
                                  nil];

NSString *searchString = @"bing.com";

if ([searchDictionary valueForKey:searchString]) {
    // search string found
} else {
    // search string not found
}
```

Note: if you want the NSDictionary to perform case-insensitive comparisons, pre-load all values lowercase, and make the search string lowercase when using valueForKey:.

How much memory this could take is a whole other story, but I don't see how this comparison could be made much faster locally. I strongly recommend the remove web service approach, though.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I do think the memory would be very, very high. Turns out, I could have to compare over 100,000 strings! That many in memory is not going to go over well. Maybe on the iPad 4, but even that would be ify. However, your idea for speed is better. Perhaps I could add a few into an NSDictionary and then compare the rest. That would at least eliminate some.

Comment: Thanks, testing is a very good call. Also, see my updated answer. I totally forgot about SQLite!

Comment: A local SQL database should be able to perform a table lookup pretty fast. It can be optimized to do searches.

Comment: I see. Your server idea is very good. I would use it, except that I really can't afford one.

Comment: I noticed from you other commend that this is for a web protection service. That changes the game a lot. I revised my answer to recommend it, but you'll want to create a remote web service that accesses a database remotely to do the lookups. This is because you can scale the web service server to increase speed as your project grows, and because you won't need to put oput a new version of the app every time you update the data source.

Comment: Actually, servers aren't expensive at all. Any hosting account can be your initial development server (MediaTemple, one of the better companies in my opinion, provides this for $20/month). When you launch and as you grow, you can use Amazon Web Services or Rackspace servers (start at about $20/month, but you need to configure them), which are cloud servers that can scale easily and quickly.

Comment: That is very true, but like I said, I'm not sure I could afford one. Do you have any idea how much this service would cost. I am a single app developer, I do not work for a company, and I just started. My income is low right now.

Comment: Sorry, your comment didn't appear. Anyway, that is actually not horrible. But I am kind of counting on the fact now that my single iOS app will provide income over $20 a month, for a while. Not to mentioned I have never worked with a server before. It's quite a jump.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be quite a learning curve if you're new to it all. You would have to use something like PHP / Ruby / Python along with a database technology such as MySQL or PostgreSQL to build the web service. You can get away with using shared hosting or dedicated hosting for a while as you grow, and if you're not familiar with configuring servers you may want to look for Managed Hosting companies.

Comment: I would be more inclined to do all of that, if I had my own group of developers or something. But I am purely an Objective-C developer, and I just don't feel that I want to set all of that up. With a server, I will have to maintain it, pretty much forever. I just can't do that. My occupation isn't an app developer, I am actually still a student. Eventually I will get a job at another company, and then my app days will be pretty much over. So, you can see why a server is not very high on my priorities right now.

Comment: Like Peter mentioned. Most of the answers here don't apply. I forgot that I need to check for a string inside all the other strings. Not just match them.

Comment: To do that, just update your code to also check whether the substring is in the search string: `if ([searchString rangeOfString:mySubstring].location != NSNotFound) { ... } `

Comment: I think I am going to try the NSDictionary. Would you mind updating your code to search for substrings. I would appreciate it. After that I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: This just occurred to me: the NSDictionary approach is only faster if you're comparing strings and not substrings. In fact, you're probably going to find the need to do other standardizations as you work on this. I think you may need to either implement SQLite, where you can factor standardizations into your query, or iterate over all your strings every time (which, as we know, is too slow for your requirements).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21084/discussion-between-anton-and-ace-legend)

Comment: True. I guess SQLite is how I'm going to have to do it. I haven't used it before, but I can try it out.

Comment: Good luck! I really hope it meets your performance requirements and that you find learning it to be fun.

Answer (score 1):

Create a string from the file and enumerate through the lines.

```
NSString *stringToCheck;

NSData *bytesOfFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/myfile.txt"];
NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytesOfFile
                                              encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
__block BOOL foundMatch = NO;

[fileString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop){
    if([stringToCheck isEqualToString:line]){
        *stop = YES;
        foundMatch = YES;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for regular expressions. Take all of the substrings you're looking for/filtering against, escape them appropriately (escaping characters such as `[`, `]`, `|`, and `\`, among others, with `\`), and join them with a `|`. The resulting string is your regular expression, which you apply to each URL.

You *could* loop through an entire array full of substrings, doing `rangeOfString:options:` with each one, but that's the slow way. [A good regular expression implementation is built for this sort of thing](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), and I would hope that [Apple's implementation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) is suitable.

That said, profile the hell out of it. I've seen some regex implementations choke on the `|` operator, so you'll want to make sure that Apple's is not one of them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make an array from a text file, where each filtered string is on it's own line. Then just use that array. There is no way I am going to manually write every line. Over 20,000 lines I need to compare. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: @AceLegend: It is certainly possible to make an array from a text file. “just use that array” is the computationally-intensive part. It will be much, much slower than a good regular expression engine. And I never said “write out the entire regular expression by hand”.

Comment: I guess I am confused on what your first paragraph means.

Comment: @AceLegend: It means loop through all your substrings and prefix every character that is special in regular expressions with a `\`, to escape it, and append each escaped substring to a larger string, separating them with `|`. This produces a single regular expression that will search any string for all of the substrings.

Comment: Alright, I get it. Anyway, I'm probably going to just try out using SQLite, as it seems like the best way to handle this. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Bah. Previous comment was meant to say “prefix every character that is special…with a [backslash], to escape it”.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I might try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare each string in your text file, you are going to have to compare it, no way around it.

What you can do however is do it on a background thread while showing some loading or something, and it won't feel as if the app got stuck.

Comment: The problem is, this all needs to happen as the webView is loading. If it takes a significant amount of time, users will get annoyed with my app for taking to long. My app is a Web Protection service. My main competition here is K9 Web protection, but that browser is SOO slow. If I can protect the user, while keeping it fast and feature-filled, I will do well. Otherwise, I am going to be left in another apps shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try with `NSDictionary` first. You can load up all your URLs into this, and internally it will use some sort of hash table/map for very quick (O(1)) lookup.

You can then check the result of `[dictionary objectForKey:userURL]`, and if it returns something then the URL matched one in the dictionary.

The only problem with this is that it requires an exact string match. If your dictionary contains `http://server/foobar` and the user enters `http://server/FOOBAR` (because it's a case-insensitive server), you are going to get a miss on your lookup. Similarly, adding `?foobar` queries to the end of URLs will result in a miss. You could also add an explicit port with `server:80`, and with `%XX` character encoding you can create hundreds of variations of the same URL. You will have to account for this and canonicalize both the URLs in your dictionary, and the URL entered by the user prior to lookup.

Comment: I guess I could give that a shot. I'll try NSDictionary, and I'll find some way to check for differences somehow.

Comment: See from my answer: "Note: if you want the NSDictionary to perform case-insensitive comparisons, pre-load all values lowercase, and make the search string lowercase when using valueForKey:."

Comment: @Anton, Alright. All strings are lowercase right now, and turning them to lowercase is easily done. However, there are other ways for the user to hit these addresses, as Mike has already mentioned.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I missed that part. @MikeWeller, great point about standardizing the strings for lookup!